# Facebook API - How to invite user to group?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I create a simple app to try invite a user to a group using facebook api.

Here is my html :

```
<form action="testinvite.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ids" id="aidi"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**testinvite.php**

```
include("facebookdata.php");
   $id = $_POST['ids'];
   if($id){
     try{
         $facebook->api('/436048536430488/members/'. $id .'/','post');
        }
     catch(FacebookApiException $e) 
     {
       echo "error";
     }
  }
```

It never success. Anyone can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: [This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/members)

Answer (score 0):

According to the facebook documentation-

> User being invited must be a user of the application. Also, users can only be invited once. Subsequent invites will fail.

These two are the only things, that I think could go wrong with your code (and with the amount of information provided in the question).

Source: [Graph API - Group Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/).