# How to invite users to facebook group with facebook api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

I need invite users to my group i tried with javascript, this is the code

```
var invitado= new Array();
invitado["member"]=("100003269899519");

FB.api("/528621163869329/members", "POST", invitado, 
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
           alert("error");
        } else { 
           alert("exito"); 
        }
    }
);
```

and returns me the following error

> "(#194) Requires all of the params: member

Please help me.

Comment: Is this code fragment complete?

Comment: see this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489276/facebook-api-how-to-invite-user-to-group

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
FB.api(
    "/528621163869329/members", 
    "POST",
    {
       "object": {
          "member": "100003269899519"
       }
    },
    function(response) {
       if (!response || response.error) {
          alert("error");
       } else { 
          alert("exito"); 
       }
    }
);
```